# Recover hp g62 bios after update failed

Tags: boot, bios

I have update the bios of hp g62 b99sl because some problem with video card, but the update was stuck at 99%... 
Now the notebook won't start...
Led of caps lock blinking to segnale that was a bios corruption...

I'm trying to restore bios pressing Win+B and then powered up, but nothing...
On pendrive there is bios file in fd extension and the same file .rom and .bin ...

Help me please

Comment: See this page...http://support.hp.com/ee-en/document/c02693833

Comment: Tried lot of time, but doesn't work :(